# query returned 3 columns in insert trigger for view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (`test_a` and `test_b`), one (`test_b`) is basically an extension of the second table (`test_a`) for certain entries to prevent primarily `NULL` value columns. To keep logical consistency of stored data I wrapped `test_b` with a view to represent the full range of values that describe the stored entity and thus require on insert into that view the full range of required information.

The insert on `table_b_view` and `table_a_view` is required to be able to return the id of the inserted entity as the application working with this db might need to keep that id for internal reference.

My current (poc) solution is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_A CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE  TEST_A (
       id     SERIAL,
       name   text,
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_A_VIEW AS
SELECT id,
       name
FROM TEST_A;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_B CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE TEST_B (
       id    int,
       second_name text,
       PRIMARY KEY(id),
       FOREIGN KEY(id)
       REFERENCES TEST_A(id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_B_VIEW AS
SELECT tb.id, name, second_name
FROM TEST_B as tb JOIN TEST_A as ta
     ON tb.id = ta.id;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_B_INSERT_FUNC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    ident int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_A_VIEW (name) VALUES (NEW.name)
    RETURNING id INTO ident;
    INSERT INTO TEST_B (id, second_name) VALUES (ident, NEW.second_name);
    RETURN ident, NEW.name, NEW.second_name;
END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;



CREATE TRIGGER TEST_B_INSERT
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON TEST_B_VIEW
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TEST_B_INSERT_FUNC();
```

Which gives me an

```
ERROR:  query "SELECT ident, NEW.name, NEW.second_name" returned 3 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_b_insert_func() line 8 at RETURN
```

when running the query

```
INSERT INTO TEST_B_VIEW(name, second_name) VALUES ('test', 'test') RETURNING id;
```

The query

```
INSERT INTO TEST_A_VIEW (name) VALUES ('test') RETURNING id;
```

works like a charm and does return me the corresponding id.

How can I fix my function or adjust my approach to be able to

1. keep the representation of the data as is (i.e., table_b as an extension of table_a which is not visible from a person just looking at the views)
2. inserts on either table have to be able to return the id used for the entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easier than expected. You have to return `NEW`, but you can 'manipulate' the values of `NEW` within the trigger.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_A CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE  TEST_A (
       id     SERIAL,
       name   text,
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_A_VIEW AS
SELECT id,
       name
FROM TEST_A;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_B CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE TEST_B (
       id    int,
       second_name text,
       PRIMARY KEY(id),
       FOREIGN KEY(id)
       REFERENCES TEST_A(id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_B_VIEW AS
SELECT tb.id, ta.name, tb.second_name
FROM TEST_B as tb JOIN TEST_A as ta
     ON tb.id = ta.id;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_B_INSERT_FUNC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    ident int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_A_VIEW (name) VALUES (NEW.name)
    RETURNING id INTO ident;
    INSERT INTO TEST_B (id, second_name) VALUES (ident, NEW.second_name);
    NEW.id = ident;
    RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;



CREATE TRIGGER TEST_B_INSERT
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON TEST_B_VIEW
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TEST_B_INSERT_FUNC();
```

Now the `INSERT` query works as intended:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_B_VIEW (name, second_name)
       VALUES ('test', 'test')
       RETURNING id;

 id 
----
  1
(1 row)


INSERT INTO TEST_B_VIEW (name, second_name)
       VALUES ('test', 'test')
       RETURNING id;
 id 
----
  2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, the combination of `RETURNING` the auto-generated primary key (in my case `id`) from the `INSERT` statement and assigning it's value to the `NEW` row before `RETURN`ing `NEW` from the insert trigger was the solution I need.